# Proxy all requests from one machine to another using nginx or anything else

Tags: nginx, vpn, proxy, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to proxy **all**  requests to another server saving corresponding ports and protocols?

I have a homeserver (without public ip) and VDS (with public ip). 
I also established connection between them using VPN (openVPN). 
So now, my homeserver has `10.8.0.5` ip address in virtual network.

So i am looking for an opportunity to proxy all requests coming to the VDS to homeserver (through `nginx` or `any another way`)

For instance:

- proxy ssh connections: 
  port: **22**
  protocol: **TCP**
  should be proxied to **port 22** using protocol **TCP**
- proxy http requests:
  port: **80**
  protocol: **HTTP**
  should be proxied to **port 80** using protocol **HTTP**
- proxy specific requests:
  port: **ANY PORT**
  protocol: **ANY PROTOCOL**
  should be proxied to **the same port** using **the same** protocol

Is it possible? And if yes, how can i bring it into life?
Which tools can I use?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you need NGINX or proxy? just route the traffic through VPN

Comment: @Reishin, thank you for your reply, i think routing is what I am looking for. Could you please describe a little more detailed about how i can route all incoming traffic to specific ip (e.g. 10.8.0.5)?

Comment: How to you want to connect (and configure) your VPS, when ALL connections are forwarded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your description and comment correctly, you will want to do a DNAT (Destination Network Address Translation ... also called port-forwarding) on all ports so inbound traffic (with destination address of the server itself) is port-forwarded to 10.8.0.5. That's easily accomplished in the iptables nat table.

```
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --jump DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.5
```

If you need to allow some connectivity to the server itself, place other rules allowing it before this one, as explained in your other post "[Route all traffic (except port 3336 and a few more) from eth0 to specific ip](https://serverfault.com/questions/1130659/route-all-traffic-except-port-3336-and-a-few-more-from-eth0-to-specific-ip/1132135#1132135)" on the same topic, referring to this post.