# Route all traffic (except port 3336 and a few more) from eth0 to specific ip

Tags: linux, routing, traffic

How can I route all incoming traffic from `eth0` interface to ip 10.8.0.5 (VPN tunnel)?

I need to forward incoming traffic except port 3666, to specific ip on ubuntu 22.04 machine.

In future list of ports that should not be routed will get bigger.

How can i do it the best way?

I have explained my situation here -> [Proxy all requests from one machine to another using nginx or anything else](https://serverfault.com/questions/1130369/proxy-all-requests-from-one-machine-to-another-using-nginx-or-anything-else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @frax already said, I had to use DNAT to route traffic in my case.

Hours of searching, googling, communicating with ChatGPT brought me needed result.

Firstly, i decided to use `iptables` console utility as the most powerful tool for setting up firewall and NATs.

To add port `3666` to 'exclusion list', firewall must accept incoming traffic from this port:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3666 -j ACCEPT
```

**NOTE**: my networking interface is `eth0`, it can be different in other cases. To check it out run following command:

```
ip a
```

Now, to add rule for forwarding all remaining traffic to specific ip, we can run following in command line:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.5
```

**NOTE**: my destination IP (10.8.0.5) belongs to VPN connection, established earlier. Change it to any IP address you need

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description and your other (proxy-post) correctly, you will want to do a DNAT (Destination Network Address Translation ... also called port-forwarding) on all ports apart from 3666/tcp, so inbound traffic on interface eth0 (with destination address of the server itself) is port-forwarded to 10.8.0.5. That's easily accomplished in the iptables nat table:

if you want this to happen before any other potentially exiting PREROUTING rules, as root:

```
iptables --table nat --insert PREROUTING --in-interface eth0 --jump DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.5
iptables --table nat --insert PREROUTING --in-interface eth0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 3666 --jump ACCEPT
```

or if you want it after potentially existing PREROUTING rules, as root:

```
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --in-interface eth0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 3666 --jump ACCEPT
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --in-interface eth0 --jump DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.5
```

(note `--append` instead of `--insert` and the *reversed order*)